# How to pass a variable from view to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to pass a language id for each link i click from my view to controller.
My view code is

```
  <?php foreach ($languages as $lang) { ?>
     <li>
       <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/box/<?php echo $template_data['box_id']?>/<?php echo $lang['language_name']?>"></a>
     </li>
   <?php } ?>
```

My controller is

```
public function box($box_id=null, $language_name=null, $language_id=null) {
   /// my function code
        echo $box_id;
        echo $language_name;
        echo $language_id;
   $data['languages'] = $this->Home_model->getLanguages($box_id);
  }
```

The languages array contain the language id and language name

i want the name to be in url but not the id

The url looks like this

```
http://localhost/mediabox/home/box/12/en
```

if i send the language id in url it is then visible otherwise it is not visible in the controller.
How can I get language id for each link in controller without sending it in url

Thanks

Comment: Try using sessions: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: The question is "Why isn't a variable I pass by URL visible to my controller". Ignore the answers about sessions, forms and AJAX as they are trying to answer a question that was not asked. Talk of sessions also presumes that you are trying to achieve site-wide localization which appears not to be the case from your code sample. It looks more like you are showing inventory where each item may be available in more than one language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pass the language name in the url without the ID, compare to languag_name column in table.

Lets assume you have url: `http://localhost/mediabox/home/box/en`

## controller

```
<?php
# I wont write a controller but you should know how to do that, im also writing code as if you are just focusing on getting language.
public function box( /**pass in your other uri params as needed **/ $lang_name = 'en'){
  #you could load this in the constructor so you dont have to load it each time, or in autoload.php if your using it site wide.
  $this->load->model('lang_model', 'langModel');

  #this example shows loading the library and running the function
  $this->load->library('lang_library');
  $this->lang_library->_getLang($lang);

  #this example shows putting the getLang function inside the controller itsself.
  self::_getLang($lang);
}
```

## library/private function

```
<?php
private functon _getLang($lang = 'en'){
  #run the query to retrieve the lang based on the lang_name, returns object of lang incl id
  $lang = $this->langModel->getLang($lang_name);
  if (!$lang){
    die('language not found');
  }else{
    return $lang;
  }
```

## lang model

```
<?php
public function getLang($lang_name = 'en'){
  $this->db->where('lang_name', $lang_name);
  $this->db->limit(1);
  $q = $this->db->get('languages');

  if ($q->mysql_num_rows > 0){
    return $q->result();
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

you will then have a variable with object associated to it then you can simply call `$lang->lang_name;` or `$lang->lang_id;`

## Session storage

```
<?php
#you could call this in the beginning after using an ajax `$.post();` to retrieve the ID.. the easiest route though is whats above. I use this in my REST APIs
$this->session->set_userdata('lang', $lang);
```

Comment: make sure to do xss filtering if ci doesn't do it already for you, and make sure to have error checking in  there, in that if a user types in an unknown lang. The other option is to use sessions like someone else stated. I edited code slightly to show a quick example on that.

Answer (score 3):

Your confusion is in 'passing back' to the controller.  Don't think of it as from controller => View (passing it say `$data['something']` variables).

Its basically a `<form>`, so take a look at [form helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) and then at [form validation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html).
That will give you an idea of how to create a form using codeigniter syntax.

In your controller, you would do a validation, and if it matches the language (or whatever you submit), then you can utilize sessions to save it for every page (so you don't need it in the URL).

[Sessions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) are very simple and saving an item is as easy as:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('varname', 'value');
```

Later, on every other controller, you can check the variable

```
$language = $this->session->userdata('varname');
// load language etc;
```

Comment: but you could be, or use ajax (which is still a `POST` or a `GET` request, effectively a form).

Comment: I dont want to use form I just want the language_id in my controller on clicking the link

Comment: @FaryalKhan, I get that, a FORM creates a `POST` or `GET`, as does AJAX, I think you are hung up on the fact that I said 'form'

Comment: I just want the language_id parameter in my box method to contain the id of the link that is clicked... and null when no link is clicked... can u tell me how can I send the id from my view to controller?

Comment: @FaryalKhan you have to use one of two methods, either a link is clicked which has the ID in its URL, IE: /home/box/box_id/en or you have to use an ajax post with a form and pass it that way, either way the only way to get your data from "view->controller" is via URL/URI. Whether it be via ajax, standard form, or an href that is created on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

Make a table with language ID and Language name in the database, just pass the language name to the controller and get the language ID by doing a db call.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using jQuery. Something like;

In View;

```
<ul id="language_selector">
  <?php foreach ($languages as $lang) { ?>
     <li>
       <a href="javascript:;" class="change-language" data-language="<?php echo $lang['language_name']?>" data-box="<?php echo $template_data['box_id']?>">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/default/version01/images/country_<?php echo $lang['language_name'] ?>.png" width="27" height="18" border="0" />
     </a>
   </li>
   <?php } ?> 
</ul>
```

The JS;

```
$(function() {
    $('.change-language').live('click', function() {
        var language_name = $(this).data('language');
        var box_id = $(this).data('box');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/home/box/'+language_name,
            type: 'post',
            data: 'box_id='+box_id,
            success: function( data ) {
                self.parent.location.reload(); 
            },
            error: function( data ) {
                alert('oops, try again');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The controller:

```
public function box($language) {
    $box_id = $this->input->post('box_id');

    // do a llokup on the language as suggested by @vivek
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are telling CodeIgniter that you will be receiving both the language name and id in your action.

```
public function box($box_id=null, $language_name=null, $language_id=null) {
}
```

Change that to just

```
public function box($box_id=null, $language_name=null) {
}
```

For your example URL you should then get $box_id == 12 and $language_name == 'en'.

Then lookup the language id by using it's name either in a helper or as part of a Language model as Mike suggests.